# change scene in unity and when go back the player must be in same position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I am making a game in unity where player jumps on the tile and if jumps on the wrong tile they will lose. I have added hint option in it but the issue is when I go to hint it goes to the other scene where there is hint and when I go back it goes from the start. I want my player lands on the same position where I left off.

I have tried
Here is the code in which I go back but nothing happens:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class valuestore : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    private GameObject player;

    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
       
    }

    public void GoBack()
    {
        // Retrieve the previous scene name and position from PlayerPrefs
        string previousScene = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PreviousScene");
        float previousPositionX = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PreviousTileX");
        float previousPositionY = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PreviousTileY");
        float previousPositionZ = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PreviousTileZ");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previousScene))
        {
            // Set the player's position to the previous position
            GameObject player = gameManager.GetPlayer();
            player.transform.position = new Vector3(previousPositionX, previousPositionY, previousPositionZ);

            // Load the previous scene
            SceneManager.LoadScene(previousScene);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Previous scene name not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need to save where they are on the scene before you move off it, ,so you can load it and put them back

Answer (score 0):

Alright, two problems in this code:

First, you're trying to retrieve the player `GameObject` using the `gameManager.GetPlayer()` method, but the `gameManager` variable is not declared in your code. Instead, you can use the player variable that you declared in the `Awake()` method.

Second, it seems like you're not setting the previous scene name and position in the `PlayerPrefs` correctly. Before loading the hint scene, you need to store the current scene name and player position in `PlayerPrefs` so that you can retrieve them later.

So the code would be:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class valuestore : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject player;

    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    }

    public void GoBack()
    {
        // Store the current scene name and player position in PlayerPrefs
        string currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("PreviousScene", currentScene);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PreviousTileX", player.transform.position.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PreviousTileY", player.transform.position.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PreviousTileZ", player.transform.position.z);

        // Load the hint scene
        SceneManager.LoadScene("HintScene");
    }
}
```

Just make sure to replace "`HintScene`" with the actual name of your hint scene. Also, ensure that the `GoBack()` method is called when the player wants to view the hint and that in the hint scene, you added a button or some other means for the player to return to the game. When that button is clicked, you can call the `GoBack()` method again, which will retrieve the previous scene name and player position from `PlayerPrefs` and set the player's position accordingly.

Comment: but it has an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: In your editor the player GameObject should have the tag "Player" for the GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player") did you do this?

Comment: yes the player gameobject have a tag "Player"

Comment: @MikeD Wouldn't it be better to create a singleton Player and access it directly instead of searching every scene for an object with the tag "Player" ?